# Set cursor movement field in ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I am using ncurses and I want to know , is there anyway to control cursor movement , as in setting the leftmost , rightmost cell it can reach in a particular window .

For bottomost I am using scrollok() so that the text doesnt overflow , is there anyway for left and right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X/Open Curses (e.g., ncurses) provides two groups of functions for adding text to the screen:

- those that wrap at the right margin
- those that do not wrap at the right margin

[`addstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addstr.3x.html), [`addwstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addwstr.3x.html) and similar functions ultimately call [`addch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html) or [`add_wch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_add_wch.3x.html), respectively, which ***wrap***.

[`addchstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addchstr.3x.html), [`add_wchstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_add_wchstr.3x.html) and similar functions do ***not*** ***wrap***.  You probably want these.

Comment: I want to edit the value of the right margin, is it possible ?

Comment: For that, you would create a window and write the text in that window.